# SQL Server count distinct entries in a column while showing the entire table

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I recently ran into a problem regarding counting rows.

The table I'm using has many articles, each associated to a Movement, which in turn belongs to a User. Normally, to count how many distinct movements each user has, I would do this:

```
SELECT Mov.Usuario, COUNT(DISTINCT Mov.MovID)
FROM Mov
WHERE Mov.Mov = 'Requisicion'
GROUP BY Mov.Usuario
```

This gives me a table similar to this:

[image]

However, I also need to include in this table, the data for each article, and the ID of the movement, kind of like this:

[image]

*Trimmed the results to only display rows for user CGARCIA*

It was necessary to do some joins with other tables to get the third column, so... to get the first three columns, I ran this query:

```
SELECT Mov.Usuario, Mov.MovID, Art.Descripcion1
FROM Mov
INNER JOIN CompraD
ON Mov.ID = CompraD.ID
INNER JOIN Art
ON CompraD.Articulo = Art.Articulo
WHERE Mov.Mov = 'Requisicion'
```

The problem now is... how do I get the fourth column that counts how many different MovIDs are for each user? Trying to add *COUNT (DISTINCT Mov.MovID)* at the end of the *SELECT* part and adding the *GROUP BY Mov.MovID* at the end of the query throws an error, saying:

*"Column 'Mov.MovID' from the selection list is not valid, because it's not contained in an aggregated function, or the"*

Yeah it cuts off in the middle like that.

As an added problem, this SQL statement is meant to be called from an outside program, which will allow filtering of the results by date. To do so, it displays a form asking for start and end date, and appends a *WHERE* condition at the end of the query like this:

```
SELECT Mov.Usuario, Mov.MovID, Art.Descripcion1
FROM Mov
INNER JOIN CompraD
ON Mov.ID = CompraD.ID
INNER JOIN Art
ON CompraD.Articulo = Art.Articulo
WHERE Mov.Mov = 'Requisicion'
AND Mov.FechaEmision BETWEEN 'ParameterA' AND 'ParameterB' -- This is the line added by the system
```

I have no control over this, and I cannot add the parameters to the query, as they are written by the program. I can make the program add a *GROUP BY* at the end after the conditions though.

I have tried doing stuff like obtaining the table with the data, and joining it with the table containing the rows, but since the program adds filter conditions at the end, the count result isn't being affected and counts all the rows.

How could I get around this?

Comment: Do you have to count *distinct* IDs?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes. Joining with the Art table yields multiple articles per movement, which means multiple rows with the same MovID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Mov.Usuario, Mov.MovID, Art.Descripcion1, cntMov.CountCol
FROM Mov m1
INNER JOIN CompraD c ON m1.ID = c.ID
INNER JOIN Art a ON c.Articulo = a.Articulo
OUTER APPLY 
(
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.MovID) CountCol
   FROM Mov x
   WHERE x.Mov = m1.Mov
   GROUP BY x.Usuario
) cntMov
WHERE m1.Mov = 'Requisicion'
AND m1.FechaEmision BETWEEN 'ParameterA' AND 'ParameterB'
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT Mov.Usuario, Mov.MovID, Art.Descripcion1,  
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Mov.Usuario) Cnt
FROM Mov m1
INNER JOIN CompraD c ON m1.ID = c.ID
INNER JOIN Art a ON c.Articulo = a.Articulo   
WHERE m1.Mov = 'Requisicion'
AND m1.FechaEmision BETWEEN 'ParameterA' AND 'ParameterB'
```

Comment: The idea kinda worked, but the counts don't seem to be taking into account the filters added at the end. I added a condition WHERE m1.MovID = 203, and in theory, I should get a 1 in the count column, but Im getting a 6, which is the total of movements for the user owning movement 203.

Comment: In other words, the CountCol column is being generated before the WHERE filters are applied.

Comment: It's returning 1 for every row, as they all have a unique combination of Usuario, MovID and Descripcion1.

Comment: try updated solution, if you say they are unique this should give correct count.

Comment: I think the aggregate is the problem - it should be COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Mov.Usuario) Cnt, if you want to know count per customer, not per (customer, MovID).

Comment: @SteveKass This almost solved my problem, except its giving me the number of rows, instead of the number of different MovIDs. Sorry, I should have explained myself better. I have a few MovID repeats, and what I meant to say, is that the combinations of MovID and Descripcion1 are unique. I tried to type COUNT(DISTINCT MovID) OVER (PARTITION BY Mov.Usuario) Cnt, but apparently SQL doesn't let you do that. Is that an oversight? I've searched and a lot of people seem to complain about it.

Comment: @ZoeStellan If you are going to edit the already extensive answer on an already extensive question it will become a bit of a jumble. Better just vote up and create a better answer if you have any.

Comment: @ZoeStellan: COUNT(DISTINCT) OVER () is indeed unsupported in SQL Server. That's what you need essentially and there's probably no alternative that would work for you (given that the query is not parametrisable but instead is modified by the program).

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle the DISTINCT issue, try this (idea from Plamen Ratchev):

```
WITH MovRanked AS (
  SELECT
    Mov.Usuario, Mov.MovID, Art.Descripcion1,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Mov.Usario
      ORDER BY Mov.MovID
    ) AS rk
  FROM Mov m1
  INNER JOIN CompraD c ON m1.ID = c.ID
  INNER JOIN Art a ON c.Articulo = a.Articulo   
  WHERE m1.Mov = 'Requisicion'
  AND m1.FechaEmision BETWEEN 'ParameterA' AND 'ParameterB'
)
  SELECT
    Usario, MovID, Descripcion1,
    MAX(rk) over (PARTITION BY Usario) as MovIDcount
  FROM MovRanked
```

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to put the date filter where it belongs. The program where I'm gonna use the query adds that line at the end, and optionally a GROUP BY.